# How to remove gap between axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I remove the gap between the two axis (marked in red in the image)?

[image: plot]

Here is my code:

```
af = plt.figure() # Create diagram
axes1 = af.add_axes([0.15, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8]) # Main Graph
axes2 = af.add_axes([0.4, 0.5, 0.55, 0.4]) # Small Graph
# Big diagram
axes1.hist(sample.Distance, 100)
axes1.set_xlabel('km')
axes1.set_ylabel('Number of Observations')
axes1.set_title('Distance: full dataset and sample')
# Small diagram
axes2.hist(sample2.Distance, 50)
axes2.set_xlabel('km')
af.show()
```

Comment: Where is `sample.Distance` coming from?

Comment: Sorry that is the column of interest in my dataframe (sample)